# How to delay mouseover event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, delay, mouseover

I am trying to delay mousehouver event in the jQuery below

```
document.observe('mouseover', (function (event) {
    var target = event.findElement('a[rel^=lightbox]') || event.findElement('area[rel^=lightbox]');
    if (target) {
        event.stop();
        this.start(target);
    }
}).bind(this));
},
```

I tried like this

```
document.observe('mouseover', (function (event), 2000) {
    var target = event.findElement('a[rel^=lightbox]') || event.findElement('area[rel^=lightbox]');
    if (target) {
        event.stop();
        this.start(target);
    }
}).bind(this));
},
```

But it didnt work.

Please how do i make this work ?

Thanks

I have also tried this, but hover is not working.

```
    var hoverTimeout;
       document.observe('mouseenter', (function(event){
        hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    document.observe('mouseover', (function(event){
        var target = event.findElement('a[rel^=lightbox]') ||                                                             event.findElement('area[rel^=lightbox]');
        if (target) {
            event.stop();
            this.start(target);
        }
    }).bind(this));
},
 }, 2000);
```

});

Comment: Where is jQuery? And _"But it didnt work." isn't the best description for coding problems, or any problem I believe,

Comment: I meant mouseover didnt work.

Comment: Oh. I see what you're doing now... I'm not positive, but I believe that the event will never fire when hovering over an <a> element, because the event is attached to the document.

Have you tried the simple test of using `console.log(event)` to see when 'mouseover' is getting fired?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to do this (probably with slight modifications, since I didn't test this code) to override the behavior in the Lightbox event handler, this should be placed right after you load the Lightbox script:

```
<script src="js/lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Lightbox.prototype.updateImageList = function() {
    this.updateImageList = Prototype.emptyFunction; 

    var hoverTimeout, delayMilliseconds = 2000;
    document.observe('mouseover', (function(event){
        var target = event.findElement('a[rel^=lightbox]')
            || event.findElement('area[rel^=lightbox]');
        if (target) {
            hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                event.stop();
                this.start(target);
            }, delayMilliseconds);
            target.one('mouseleave', function(){
                clearTimeout(hoverTimeout);
            });
        }
    }).bind(this));
};
</script>
```

Comment: I did this, but mouseover did not work 
` 
        var hoverTimeout;
document.observe('mouseenter', (function(event){
    hoverTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        document.observe('mouseover', (function(event){
            var target = event.findElement('a[rel^=lightbox]') || event.findElement('area[rel^=lightbox]');
            if (target) {
                event.stop();
                this.start(target);
            }
        }).bind(this));
    },
     }, 2000);
});`

Comment: It looks like the events names are 'mouseover' and 'mouseout' -- my jQuery is getting in the way of my JavaScript. :P

Comment: I am using a Lightbox plugin, and i have only copied the part that has the mouseover event.

Could it be that some other line of code is affecting it.?

Comment: I've rewritten the code to react to hovers over the lightbox links... but I may not be understanding the whole problem.. do you have a link to the page in question?

Comment: I still cant get it to work. here is the page I am working on [link](http://goo.gl/sIJOz) . Thanks

Comment: I've updated my code to override Lightbox's event handler. Let me know whether or not it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried it but it didnt work. The mouseover didnt fire.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the hoverIntent plugin, I think it's just what you're looking for :).
http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: I downloaded the JS and added it to my project, but didn work.

Is there a way i can just add the second to the project i already have ?